# Neo4J (Cypher) query to find all paths that do not follow a pattern

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k3bU.png)

I would like to get the path from Label_1 to Label_5 that does not follow a pre-defined pattern. In particular, I would like to get the path that does not follow the pattern: `Label_1 -> Label_2 -> Label_3 -> Label_4 -> Label_5`

As you can see in the graph, the lower branch (after Label_1) is following this pattern and the upper branch is not following this pattern since we have `Label_1 -> Label_2 -> Label_4 -> Label_5`

This  means that I am searching for a query that would return: `Label_1 -> Label_2 -> Label_4 -> Label_5`

I tried the following query, but this one does not return any result.

```
MATCH p=(e1n:Label_1)-[*]->(e2:Label_5)
WHERE NOT (:Label_1)-->(:Label_2)-->(:Label_3)-->(:Label_4)-->(:Label_5)
RETURN p
```

Since I am new to Neo4j and Cypher, I would like to ask how I can write such a query and why my approach with WHERE NOT is not working.

For the creation I used the following Create commands:

```
CREATE (a:Label_1 {name: "Label_1"})
CREATE (b:Label_2 {name: "Label_2"})
CREATE (c:Label_2 {name: "Label_2"})
CREATE (d:Label_3 {name: "Label_3"})
CREATE (e:Label_4 {name: "Label_4"})
CREATE (f:Label_5 {name: "Label_5"})
CREATE (a)-[:FOLLOWS]->(b)
CREATE (a)-[:FOLLOWS]->(c)
CREATE (b)-[:FOLLOWS]->(d)
CREATE (c)-[:FOLLOWS]->(e)
CREATE (d)-[:FOLLOWS]->(e)
CREATE (e)-[:FOLLOWS]->(f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for why your filtering isn't working, the pattern in your WHERE clause doesn't apply specifically to your MATCHed path. You're asking it to filter out the result if such a pattern doesn't exist in your entire graph. Since there is an occurrence of the pattern going from :Label_1 to :Label_5 like that in your graph, your MATCH will always fail.

You can try instead collecting the paths you want to exclude and filtering such that any MATCHed paths aren't in the excluded set:

```
MATCH path = (:Label_1)-->(:Label_2)-->(:Label_3)-->(:Label_4)-->(:Label_5)
WITH collect(path) as excluded
MATCH p=(e1n:Label_1)-[*]->(e2:Label_5)
WHERE NOT p IN excluded
RETURN p
```